# Event Binding using Angular on an HTML input element

Tags: angular, events, binding, handler

I am having a hard time understanding this type of error in angular:  **(TS) Element implicitly has an 'any' type because of Expression of type 'setAttribute' can't be used to index type EventTarget.  Property 'setAttribute' does not exist on type EventTarget**.

I'm working on a project where I have an SVG map and it is interactive.  I mouse over a country and it pulls the data about that country from the api.  A snippet is below.  But I am getting compilations error on the `e.target["setAttribute"]("fill", "red")` from the map-image.component.ts.  I don't understand what am I doing wrong and can't find what that error means.

I then changed the e to any:

```
    pieces.forEach((e: any) => {

      e.addEventListener("mouseenter", e =>

        e.target["setAttribute"]("fill", "red")

      );
```

and compilation error is fixed, but no data is being pulled from the api.

**map-service.ts**:

```
  getCountry(countryCode: string) {

    return this

      .http

      .get("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/" + countryCode + "?format=json");

  }
```

**map-image.component.ts**:

```
export class MapImageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @Output() onSelection: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();



  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let pieces = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("path"));



    pieces.forEach(e => {

      e.addEventListener("mouseenter", e =>

        e.target["setAttribute"]("fill", "red")

      );
```

**map.component.ts**:

```
  loadCountryData(e: any) {

      this.country.name = e.name;



      this.mapService

        .getCountry(e.countryCode)

        .pipe(take(1))

        .subscribe((response: any) => {

          this.country.data = [

            "Name: " + response[1][0].name,

            "Capital: " + response[1][0].capitalCity,

            "Region: " + response[1][0].region.value,

            "Income Level: " + response[1][0].incomeLevel.value

          ];

        });

  }
```

**map.component.html**:

```html
<div class="row columns">

  <div class="col pr-5">

    <app-map-image (onSelection)="loadCountryData($event)"></app-map-image>

  </div>



    <div class="col-4">

      <div class="card">

        <div class="card-body">

          <h5 class="card-title">{{ country?.name }}</h5>

          <div class="card-text">

            <ul>

              <li *ngFor="let o of country?.data || []">

                {{ o }}

              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You probably have `noImplicitAny` set to true in your .tsconfig

Comment: I can't see any `path` element in your html. Are you sure you get any objects?

Comment: Just as a warning, direct DOM manipulation is very much an anti-pattern in Angular. This is most certainly not the way to achieve the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler what `e.target` actually is:

```
e.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event: MouseEvent) =>
  (event.target as HTMLElement).setAttribute("fill", "red");
);
```

Also you're shadowing the `e` variable which isn't great for readability, so I renamed it to `event`.

I also don't know what your `e` element actually is so I just put `HTMLElement` as the type. If you're using something like a div for example you can change it do `HTMLDivElement`, or any type corresponding to the element you have. It's fine to leave it as is however as adding a more specific type in this scenario won't do anything.